# Python. Помогите в отладке программы

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, написал программу, которая из любого текстового поля копирует текст, производит над ним некоторую операцию (метод `switch`) и вставляет обратно. Всё хорошо, программа работает, но есть проблема: работает через раз. То вставит то, что в буфере обмена, то вставит строку, не пропустив через метод `switch`, то вообще ничего не вставит. В общем, полная ахинея. Предполагаю, что всё дело в задержке методов pyperclip'a, но как убрать задержку не знаю. Если это сделать невозможно - посоветуйте, как имитировать нажатие клавиш.
Текст программы:

```
from Switcher import switch
from pynput import keyboard
from pyperclip import copy, paste
import win32com.client


class Main:
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')

    def on_click(self, key):
        if str(key) == 'Key.f7':
            # Вытаскиваем из буфера то, что там сейчас есть
            buffer = paste()

            # Выделяем и вырезаем текст из текстового поля
            self.shell.SendKeys('^a^x')

            # Вытаскиеваем транслит-строку, переводим и вставляем в буфер
            copy(switch(paste()))

            # Вставляем текст нажатием Ctrl + V
            self.shell.SendKeys('^v')

            # Вставляем в буфер старые данные
            copy(buffer)

    def on_release(self, key):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        with keyboard.Listener(
                on_press=self.on_click,
                on_release=self.on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()

main = Main()
```

UPD: 
Попробовал доунгрейднуться на Python 2.7 с его SendKeys, проблема сохраняется, программа ведёт себя так же, как и вела:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Switcher import switch
from pynput import keyboard
from clipboard import copy, paste
from SendKeys import *


class Main:
    def on_click(self, key):
        if str(key) == 'Key.f7':
            # Вытаскиваем из буфера то, что там есть
            buffer = paste()

            # Выделяем и вырезаем текст из текстового поля
            SendKeys('^a^x', pause=0, turn_off_numlock=False)

            # Вытаскиеваем транслит-строку, переводим и вставляем в буфер
            copy(switch(paste()))

            # Вставляем текст нажатием Ctrl + V
            SendKeys('^v', pause=0,  turn_off_numlock=False)
            # Вставляем в буфер старые данные
            copy(buffer)

    def on_release(self, key):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        with keyboard.Listener(
                on_press=self.on_click,
                on_release=self.on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()


main = Main()
```

Comment: А исключения возникaют?

Comment: @AndrioSkur нет, исключений не вылетает. Пробовал ещё обернуть имитацию нажатия клавиш в потоки. Получилось, но программа стала выполняться 2-3 секунды, что неприемлемо, конечно.

Comment: А можете обновить вопрос в соответствии с текущими наработками?

Comment: @gil9red обновил

Comment: У вас кст тоже вызовы `keybd_event` по 5 секунд происходят? :) Добрался до вашего кода, попробовал и немного удивился медленному выполнению кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось улучшить скорость программы, используя `win32api` и оборачивая всё это в поток. Таким образом вырезание текста происходит с помощью:

```
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0)  # CTRL press
win32api.keybd_event(65, 0, 0, 0)  # A
win32api.keybd_event(88, 0, 0, 0)  # X
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_CONTROL, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)  # CTRL release
```

UPD: 
По просьбе дополняю

```
    def cut():
        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0)  # CTRL press
        keybd_event(65, 0, 0, 0)  # A (ACSII)
        keybd_event(88, 0, 0, 0)  # X
        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)  # CTRL release

    @staticmethod
    def paste():
        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0)  # CTRL press
        keybd_event(86, 0, 0, 0)  # V
        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)  # CTRL release

    def on_click(self, key):
        if str(key) == 'Key.f7':
            # Вытаскиваем из буфера то, что там есть
            buf = paste()

            # Выделяем и вырезаем текст из текстового поля
            t1 = Thread(target=self.cut)
            t1.start()
            t1.join()

            # Вытаскиеваем транслит-строку, переводим и вставляем в буфер
            copy(self.switch(paste()))

            # Вставляем текст нажатием Ctrl + V
            t1 = Thread(target=self.paste)
            t1.start()
            t1.join()

            # Вставляем в буфер старые данные
            copy(buf)

    def __init__(self):
        with keyboard.Listener(
                on_press=self.on_click,
                on_release=self.on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()
```

Comment: Молодец, что разобрались :) Ваш код это аналог `SendKeys('^a^x', pause=0, turn_off_numlock=False)`? А можете к ответу приложить весь код с исправлением? :)

Comment: @gil9red дополнил

Comment: Спасибо, интересно потом будем с кодом поиграться :)